# Use Mockito matchers for array elements

Tags: arrays, mockito, matcher

I have a method like this:

```
String m(String s, Object[] args);
```

and I can specify a behaviour for it like:

```
when(x.m(
            eq("expected string"), 
            Matchers.<Object[]>any()
)).thenReturn(expectedValue);
```

But I want to be more specific and to be able to specify something like *"any array that has 2 elements where the second one is null"*. So, as a "pseudocode", I want to use:

```
when(x.m(
            eq("expected string"), 
            Matchers.<Object[]>any(){anyString(), isNull()}
)).thenReturn(expectedValue);
```

Is this possible in Mockito?

As a workaround I could use `verify` in order to check the type of the elements 
from that array, but I'd like to validate them in the `when` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mockito `argTaht` to use your custom matcher.
In your case you can implement it like this:

```
when(x.m(anyString(), argThat((Object[] o) -> o.length == 2 && o[0] instanceof String && o[1] == null)))
                .thenReturn("mocked value");
```

Of course, you can add some more validation and check if need so.
And now if you call it like this, you will get the mocked value:

```
String mocked = x.m("string", new Object[]{"string", null});
assertEquals("mocked value", mocked);
```

Any other call will return `null`:

```
String notMocked = x.m("string", new Object[]{"string", "string"});
assertNull(notMocked);
```